# fill-up missing column value from another dblink table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here is my data model:

[image: Please click here for table structure]

I need to populate a missing column value from another dblink table

```
select s.fmbs_cd,fmbs_nm,sum(SAL) SALE from sales S,FMBS C
where s.fmbs_cd=c.fmbs_cd(+)
group by s.fmbs_cd,fmbs_nm;
```

My main table would be FMBS table, not dblink table, I want to use dblink table only for missing values.

Comment: Use `coalesce` function

Answer (score 0):

Link sale and FMBS@S_ORC

select s.fmbs_cd,c.fmbs_nm,sum(s.SAL) SALE from sales S inner join FMBS@S_ORC C on s.fmbs_cd=c.fmbs_cd left outer join FMBS f on c.fmbs_cd=f.fmbs_cd group by s.fmbs_cd,c.fmbs_nm